# Sending a SIGCONT fails silently with unpredictable behavior - linux

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, child-process

I'm toying around with processes and signals on linux, below is a simple test I wrote in C:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void work(void);

int main(void) {
    pid_t children[10];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid == -1) {
            perror("parent: error forking");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if(pid == 0) {
            raise(SIGSTOP); // child stops itself
            work(); // after resuming it goes on to execute work()
            return EXIT_SUCCESS; // and finally, it successfully terminates
        } else {
            fprintf(stdout, "parent: spawned child (%d)\n", pid);
            children[i] = pid;
        }
    }

    // parent spawned all 10 children who are now stopped - begin resuming them one by one
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fprintf(stdout, "parent: signaling child (%d) to continue...\n", children[i]);
        if(kill(children[i], SIGCONT) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "parent: error signalling child (%d) to continue: %s\n", children[i], strerror(errno));
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS; // exit from parent once all children have been resumed
}

void work(void) {
    pid_t mypid = getpid();
    srand(mypid);
    int32_t sleep_time = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    fprintf(stdout, "(%d): began sleeping for %d seconds\n", mypid, sleep_time);
    sleep(sleep_time);
    fprintf(stdout, "(%d): done sleeping after %d seconds\n", mypid, sleep_time);
}
```

The idea is the following:

---

The parent spawns 10 child processes, each of which sends itself a `SIGSTOP` immediately after it's spawned. Once the parent successfully spawns all 10 processes, it begins sending all 10 of them a `SIGCONT` immediately.

Once a child process is resumed, it starts executing `work()` (which simply suspends its execution for a random time between 0 and 10 seconds, printing information to stdout along the way), after which it successfully terminates.

---

This is what successfull output looks like:

```
[I] bogdan in ~/dev/mserve
>>  ./prog
parent: spawned child (138655)
parent: spawned child (138656)
parent: spawned child (138657)
parent: spawned child (138658)
parent: spawned child (138659)
parent: spawned child (138660)
parent: spawned child (138661)
parent: spawned child (138662)
parent: spawned child (138663)
parent: spawned child (138664)
parent: signaling child (138655) to continue...
(138655): began sleeping for 9 seconds
parent: signaling child (138656) to continue...
(138656): began sleeping for 3 seconds
parent: signaling child (138657) to continue...
parent: signaling child (138658) to continue...
parent: signaling child (138659) to continue...
parent: signaling child (138660) to continue...
parent: signaling child (138661) to continue...
parent: signaling child (138662) to continue...
parent: signaling child (138663) to continue...
parent: signaling child (138664) to continue...
(138659): began sleeping for 4 seconds
(138657): began sleeping for 5 seconds
(138658): began sleeping for 7 seconds
(138660): began sleeping for 10 seconds
(138663): began sleeping for 3 seconds
(138662): began sleeping for 7 seconds
(138664): began sleeping for 7 seconds
(138661): began sleeping for 2 seconds
[I] bogdan in ~/dev/mserve
(138661): done sleeping after 2 seconds
(138656): done sleeping after 3 seconds
(138663): done sleeping after 3 seconds
(138659): done sleeping after 4 seconds
(138657): done sleeping after 5 seconds
(138658): done sleeping after 7 seconds
(138662): done sleeping after 7 seconds
(138664): done sleeping after 7 seconds
(138655): done sleeping after 9 seconds
(138660): done sleeping after 10 seconds
```

As is indicated by the info messages, all 10 processes successfully finished their sleep and terminated.

## The problem

Perhaps once out of every 3 times, a random number of the 10 child proccesses gets "stuck" and fails to resume after the SIGSTOP. The `kill(2)` from the parent that sends the SIGCONT succeeds, but the proccess(es) remain in the suspended state.

The output then looks like this:

```
[I] bogdan in ~/dev/mserve
>  ./alt
parent: spawned child (139369)
parent: spawned child (139370)
parent: spawned child (139371)
parent: spawned child (139372)
parent: spawned child (139373)
parent: spawned child (139374)
parent: spawned child (139375)
parent: spawned child (139376)
parent: spawned child (139377)
parent: spawned child (139378)
parent: signaling child (139369) to continue...
parent: signaling child (139370) to continue...
parent: signaling child (139371) to continue...
parent: signaling child (139372) to continue...
parent: signaling child (139373) to continue...
parent: signaling child (139374) to continue...
parent: signaling child (139375) to continue...
parent: signaling child (139376) to continue...
parent: signaling child (139377) to continue...
parent: signaling child (139378) to continue...
(139371): began sleeping for 4 seconds
(139369): began sleeping for 8 seconds
(139373): began sleeping for 7 seconds
(139370): began sleeping for 3 seconds
(139375): began sleeping for 9 seconds
(139372): began sleeping for 7 seconds
(139374): began sleeping for 10 seconds
(139376): began sleeping for 8 seconds
(139377): began sleeping for 7 seconds
[I] bogdan in ~/dev/mserve
(139370): done sleeping after 3 seconds
(139371): done sleeping after 4 seconds
(139373): done sleeping after 7 seconds
(139372): done sleeping after 7 seconds
(139377): done sleeping after 7 seconds
(139369): done sleeping after 8 seconds
(139376): done sleeping after 8 seconds
(139375): done sleeping after 9 seconds
(139374): done sleeping after 10 seconds
```

This time only 9 proccesses successfully finished (9 "done sleeping" messages were printed).

By executing `$ ps au` in the shell I can observe the "stuck" processes (note the `T` status):

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
bogdan    139378  0.0  0.0   2312    80 pts/3    T    20:31   0:00 ./prog
```

I can even signal them to continue from my shell:

```
$ kill -SIGCONT 139378
```

```
(139378): began sleeping for 5 seconds
...
(139378): done sleeping after 5 seconds
```

---

### Another weird detail

When executing the parent process with `strace` (e.g. `$ strace ./program`), the problem never occurs, all 10 proccesses get properly resumed 100% of the time. It's only when I execute the parent directly from my shell that I can observe the problem.

I have gone over the `signal(7)` manpage a few times now but I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Be careful about using `strace`. IIRC, it uses `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` so it [probably] invalidates your results. You _do_ have a race condition as outlined in the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the failure to resume happens in the event that the parent delivers a `SIGCONT` to a child that has not yet stopped itself.  Such a signal will be ignored, since the process is not stopped at the time it is handled.

Nothing in your program prevents this from happening; instead, you are simply relying on the children to get around to stopping faster than the parent gets around to signaling them -- a race condition.  The fact that you can resume the stuck process by sending an (additional) `SIGCONT` to it is consistent with this diagnosis, and it is plausible that `strace` affects the timing enough that the children always win their races.

Comment: It's interesting to me that the parent can send 9 SIGCONT's to 9 different child processes faster than it takes one processes to signal itself to stop. In the "wrong" output of my OP, the processes that was left suspended was the last one in the "list", meaning that the parent spawned all 10, signalled 9, but the 10th one still wasn't fast enough ti signal itself? (perhaps some voodoo scheduling magic that I'm totally unfamiliar with). Nevertheless, thank you!

Comment: @bool3max, unless your machine has at least 11 cores, it's not just a question of how fast each process is.  It's also a question of when each gets any CPU time scheduled for it.  It's not surprising, really, that the last is the one that hangs, because starting processes is slow, whereas dispatching signals is fast(er).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a race condition between child processes sending itself `SIGSTOP` and the parent process sending `SIGCONT`. Sometimes the parent process sends `SIGCONT` before the child sent `SIGSTOP`, hence the child hangs.